# Do commercial passenger airplanes have cambered airfoils?

Tags: wing, airfoil, airplane

It seems to me that they logically would, since they have no need to fly upside down like an aerobatic plane would (so they would not need a symmetric airfoil for any conceivable reason). That being said, is that correct, and does anyone have a link to a reliable source where that is stated?

Comment: Look at pictures of wings.

Comment: Related: [Why does the wing root of the A330 have a pronounced twist?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44039/14897)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's safe to say that all passenger planes use cambered airfoils, although I wouldn't be surprised if someone finds a case of an aerobatic plane being used to carry a paying passenger, just to prove me wrong.

There's a fairly comprehensive list [here](https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/aircraft.html). You'd have to look them up to be sure, but many of them use codes that indicate thickness and camber. For example, [the first digit of a NACA airfoil is the camber](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/naca4digit).