# What is the typical wing twist angle at the wing tip for a commercial jet?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing

I'm trying to find this information for commercial jets. It is nowhere to be found. Does anyone know typical values?

Comment: Do you mean the built in wing twist to adjust for lift distribution across the wing, or the induced twist that can occur when making use of your ailerons?

Comment: @Noddle Built in wing twist.

Comment: This is usually called wing washout or washin (depending on which way it twists), which may help your search

Answer (score 3):

For an A310 we start from the attack of the engines with an angle of attack of the profile of 3 degrees, and we arrive at the wing tip to -3 degrees. In general along the wing the twist angle is around 2-3 degrees, it is near the tip that changes and arrive until a negative value.

[image: A310 Swept wing]

Answer (score 2):

Commercial jets are special because they change airfoil shape over span quite dramatically to reduce the effects of sweep on local lift. Also, the lift force on a backward swept wing causes it to twist, so washout in flight is several degrees higher than on the ground.

In order to compensate for the much higher zero-lift angle of attack of the [modified root airfoil](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44039/why-does-the-wing-root-of-the-a330-have-a-pronounced-twist/44045#44045), its incidence is very high. If you use the fuselage axis as a reference, in case of the A330 and A340 the incidence changes from +4.5° at the root to 0° between 30% and 70% span and -2° at the tip when on the ground and -2° at 70% span and -5° at the tip in flight.